# java - JDialog closing refresh JFrame issue

Tags: java, swing

The scenario is that I have a JTable on my JFrame named "MainFrame" and I can edit the data saved in a xml file using a JDialog named "EditFrame". I can change the data in the xml file by click the save button on "EditFrame" but it won't reload the JTable on "MainFrame". The code for MainFrame is as below:

```
package ca.ism.wen.gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
...
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    static JTable jt = null;
    static List<RdpServ> rdps = null;
    static Vector<String> header = null;
    static Vector<Vector<String>> data = null;
    static TableModel tm = null;

    public MainFrame(){

        header = new Vector<String>();
        ...         
        loadData();

        jt = new JTable(tm);

        Container con = this.getContentPane();
        JScrollPane p = new JScrollPane(jt);
        con.add(p);

        JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
        btnEdit.setActionCommand("Edit");
        btnEdit.addActionListener(this);
        JButton btnLogout = new JButton("Logout");
        btnLogout.setActionCommand("Logout");
        btnLogout.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.add(btnEdit);
        jp.add(btnLogout);
        con.add(jp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
        if (cmd.equals("Edit")) {
            EditFrame ef = new EditFrame();
            ef.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            @Override
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                    refresh();
                }
            });
        }
        else if (cmd.equals("Logout")) {
            UserDao.signoff();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void refresh(){
        loadData();
        jt.repaint();

    }

    public static void loadData(){
        rdps= UserDao.getRs();
        data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        for (RS rdp:rdps){
            Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
            ...
            data.add(v);
        }

        tm = new DefaultTableModel(data,header){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
            {
                return false;
            }
        };

    }
}
```

I googled a lot and tried the solution online. None of them works for my code. Please help. Thanks, guys!!!

Comment: Assuming `EditFrame` is a modal dialog.  You could just wait till it returns and then refresh the table then (modal dialogs block till they are closed).  Also, depending on how you've set up `EditFrame`, `windowClosed` my not be triggered...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, i think he didn't add the model back to the table as his code shows my. I have indicated that in the answer.

Comment: @Sage While a good point, it's difficult to know with only the snippet of code to go by. You could be right though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tm = new DefaultTableModel(data,header){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
        {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Ok, after creating the model i don't see you added the `model` back to the `table` inside the `loadData()` function. After creating the `tm` try: `jt.setmodel(tm)`, as `jt` is your table instance inside the `loadData()` function.

`jt`, `tm` wired name, hard to understand: make them a little bigger, such as: `jTable`, `tModel` etc

**Edit:**

```
public static void loadData(){
        rdps= UserDao.getRs();
        data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        for (RS rdp:rdps){
            Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
            ...
            data.add(v);
        }

        tm = new DefaultTableModel(data,header){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
            {
                return false;
            }
        };

       jt.setModel(tm);  // <------------------- here

    }
```

Comment: Hi Sage, thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion. At the end of loadData() function, I added 
      jt = new JTable();
      jt.setModel(tm);
Of course, I remove "jt=new JTable(tm);" in the MainFrame constructor. However, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user2962555, why you are emoving the `jTable` ? you don't need to create another jTable. Your earlier implementation is fine. Just call `jt.setModel(tm)` inside the `load()` function. Check the edit

Comment: It worked. Yeah!!!
Thank you so much, Sage. I really appreciate your help. Also, I will change my identifier name based on your suggestion. Thanks!!